# How to use the -C option correctly in Make

Tags: c, makefile, build, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I need to compile [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2000947) program in my archlinux install.

When I do, as instructed in that thread:

```
make -j4 -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules
```

I get the following error:

```
 make -j4 -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules
scripts/Makefile.build:41: /home/jenia/Documents/kernel-modules/camera/Makefile: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target '/home/jenia/Documents/kernel-modules/camera/Makefile'.  Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:2021: /home/jenia/Documents/kernel-modules/camera] Error 2
```

The makefile is indeed not located in `/home/jenia/Documents/kernel-modules/camera/Makefile` but rather in:

```
ls -l /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/Makefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 71855 Mar  3 10:58 /lib/modules/6.2.2-arch1-1/build/Makefile
```

How do I correctly point make to `lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/Makefile`? Notice that I'm using the `-C` flag already but to no avail.

Comment: make -f <path_to_makefile>?

Comment: This isn't so much about `make` in general as it is about the Linux kernel build system (which relies on `make`).

Answer (score 0):

<sup>*Semi-informed speculation.*</sup>

You have:

```
make -j4 -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules
```

The `M=$(pwd)` records the directory you are running the build from, and is probably used in the `makefile` to identify where the included makefile (some subset of `kernel-modules/camera/Makefile`) should be found.  But you don't have that in your `/home/jenia/Documents` directory.

Without having tested it in the slightest, I think your problem is that your current directory needs to be closer to where the software is located.  I'm not sure exactly which directory, but `/lib/modules` might be a reasonable guess (therefore, it is probably wrong).

But the key point is:

- Make sure you launch the build from the correct/expected directory.

Your use of `-C` is fine; the problem is the `M=$(pwd)` part.

Note that the file `/lib/modules/6.2.2-arch1-1/build/Makefile` is probably not the one that the `scripts/Makefile.build` is looking for; that should be in a sub-directory `camera` somewhere.

---

In support of my theory about 'start from correct directory', I note that [comment #19](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2000947/comments/19) in the linked article says:

> First, enable source code repositories, then fetch the source code with the following in terminal
>
> ```
> apt-get source linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)
> ```
>
> Then navigate to the `/drivers/media/usb/uvc` directory and rename the `uvcdriver.c` to `uvcdriver.old`, choose open directory in terminal then
>
> ```
> wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Giuliano69/uvc_driver-for-Quanta-HD-User-Facing-0x0408-0x4035-/main/uvc_driver.c
>
> make -j4 -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules
> sudo cp uvcvideo.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/media/usb/uvc/
> ```
>
> Then see if it works

This suggests you should launch your build from the `/drivers/media/usb/uvc` directory.

Comment: `makefile` is not the correct file name.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I correctly point make to `lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/Makefile`?

In light of the `make` command you are executing, the error messages you report indicate that you already have directed `make` to that makefile.  The main error is coming from a sub-`make`, so the top-level makefile must have been found.

> When I do, as instructed in that thread:
>
> ```
> make -j4 -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules
> ```
>
> I get the following error:
>
> ```
>  make -j4 -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules
> scripts/Makefile.build:41: /home/jenia/Documents/kernel-modules/camera/Makefile: No such file or directory
> make[1]: *** No rule to make target '/home/jenia/Documents/kernel-modules/camera/Makefile'.  Stop.
> make: *** [Makefile:2021: /home/jenia/Documents/kernel-modules/camera] Error 2
> ```

That error seems to indicate that although you are executing a command that you drew from the referenced thread, you have not fully followed the instructions there:

> **First**, enable source code repositories, then fetch the source code with the following in terminal
>
> ```bash
> apt-get source linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)
> ```
>
> **Then** navigate to the `/drivers/media/usb/uvc` directory and rename the `uvcdriver.c` to `uvcdriver.old`, choose open directory in terminal **then**
>
> ```bash
> wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Giuliano69/uvc_driver-for-Quanta-HD-User-Facing-0x0408-0x4035-/main/uvc_driver.c
>
> make -j4 -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules
>
> sudo cp uvcvideo.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/media/usb/uvc/
> ```

(Emphasis and some formatting added.)

It's not clear exactly which instructions you have followed and which not, but certainly you are running the `make` command from a different directory than `/drivers/media/usb/uvc`.  Likely you have performed the `wget` command in whatever directory you are running the build from as well, instead of from the one specified in the instructions.  I can't tell whether you have run the `apt-get` command or not.

There may be other ways to do it, but you cannot expect it to work to pick and choose only some of a particular set of instructions.